# a tag doesn't download properly

Tags: javascript, html, file, tags

I am building a React App, but the problem is that I want to download a file on a button click.

It starts to download but right away, an alert pops up and it says

> One download failed

And the notification appears as

> file.html - No file

I don't know why it is saved as html and not pdf

It should be that Chrome notification that says: "Downloading".

Here is my button:

```
<button>
  <a href="declaratie-unica.pdf" id="download" download="declaratie-unica.pdf">
    Descarcă
    <i className="fa-solid fa-download"></i>
  </a>
</button>
```

And bere is the structure of my `components` folder:
[image]

I am working on replit.com and I saw another question like these and one of the answers said that it is because of the server that is `localhost`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is the file in the same folder as indicated by the url? is a rewrite involved?

Comment: @Psi as You can see `declaratie-unica.pdf` is in the same folder as the `RedirectSteps` component. Ghete is my `a` tag for Downloading.

Comment: this may be, but what url is the browser showing?

Comment: @Psi sorry for the spelling but I am not American or English and my keyboard automatically corects the words to Romanian. It shows only the url, I mean no 'file.pdf' added to the url.

Comment: It doesn't matter where your component is in the file system, the browser only cares about the url to the file relative from the servers root path or relative from the current URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the pdf file to the public folder.

Everything in the public folder are not touched by webpack (or whichever bundler is used), and are available as is from the frontend.